# Hyperledger Composer Query with Optional Parameters

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to create a dynamic query and I can't seem to find any documentation that would help. I have the following transaction. I would like to create a query that can potentially take any number of the fields, but it seems that whenever I create a query with a variable, it makes it required and if I don't provide it, they query errors out.

```
transaction QuantityChange {
      o String partNumber
      o String facilityId
      o Double quantity
      o invType invType
      o appType application
      o String refDocId optional
}
```

For instance, if I make the following query, I have to provide both Part and Facility or the query does not return.

```
query myTransactions{
  description: "return all QuantityChange transactions made"
  statement: 
  SELECT org.acme.trading.QuantityChange
  WHERE ((partNumber == _$part) AND ( facilityId == _$facility))
}
```

Can anyone point me to some resources to help me make more dynamic queries?

Answer (score 1):

There are examples where people have created many queries to cover the combinations of parameters they wish to query, but that is a simplistic approach and doesn't scale well.

You can build a dynamic query using the Composer API, specifically the `buildQuery` and `query` methods.  These are available in the Client API and also the Runtime API so they can be used within Transaction logic.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/client-businessnetworkconnection#buildquery